# Closing TCP socket from both sides leaves socket alive

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, time-wait

I have created a TCP socket on Linux using C.  Client `connect()`'s to server and server `accept()`'s it.  When the client request has been served - or a timeout has occured - I want that socket to be totally closed.

But, although both sides call the `close()` function, I see in the terminal that the socket lives on for a few more minutes in the `TIME_WAIT` state.

The question is, how can I totally kill it?

Keep in mind that I do not need any handshake with `FIN` and `ACK` flags, that I have seen while Googling.

EDIT: I have seen this [Avoiding TIME_WAIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931043/avoiding-time-wait) thread, but it's 9 years old, that's why I do not fully trust it.

Also, the communication I want to achieve is inter-process communication in the local host, and it must be possible to open and close up to 100 connections per second. That's why, I do not need any handshaking. And I do not want the sockets to remain at TIME_WAIT state for neither a minute, because the OS fills with sockets and the performance is significantly decreased.

EDIT 2: Finally I used SO_REUSEPORT flag and there is no lag trying to open new connection, if the OS is alread filled up...

UDP sockets do not satisfy my program's other specs...

Comment: Please expand on "Keep in mind that I do not need any handshake with FIN and ACK flags" because one of the reasons you can see a long TIME_WAIT is the closing handshaking was not completed and the system will not return the socket for reuse in case late packets drift in and interfere with the next connection.

Comment: The only way would be to send a RST, so the TIME_WAIT state is never entered. Many browsers (used to?) do so when closing a connection to the web server for that reason.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160347/close-vs-shutdown-socket

Comment: This is normal for TCP. The only way I know of is to tune your system to cycle through time_wait state more quickly.

Comment: You *do* need the FIN/ACK handshake, whether you believe it or not.

Comment: Unfortunately, *Avoiding TIME_WAIT* is still valid information. But if you need to open and close 100 connections per second, you probably want UDP and not TCP... Without more detail this post is indeed a duplicate (same question and same answer). If you only send single messages per connection without any handshake, then you should use UDP - but this is not what this question asks for...

Comment: It leave the *local port* alive at one end. The sockets at both ends are closed and of no further use.